# Launching activity from braodcast receiver registered with application context

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to launch an activity from a broadcast receiver for custom intents. I don't want multiple instances of that activity, so I am not using new task flag.

I have registered those receivers in the manifest. I am getting an error

```
"03-02 12:54:58.634: W/System.err(3763): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"
```

**Where should I register my receivers?** When tried registering in activity, receiver could launch activity.
 What may be going wrong when registered in manifest?

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    System.out.println ( "Application Started" );
    // put your TimerTask calling class here

    try
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent ( context, AutoStartExampleActivity.class );
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println ( " Error while Starting Activity " + e.toString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Activity` override the `startActivity()` method of the `Context`, so if you call `startActivity()` in an Activity, there will be no problems, but if you call it from `context`, you should add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Register the receiver in android manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.XYZReceiver"></receiver>
```